# Are projective modules over $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_m]$ free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, projective-module, free-modules

The [Quillen-Suslin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quillen%E2%80%93Suslin_theorem) states that any finitely generated projective module over $\mathbb{k}[x_1,...,x_m]$ is free, for $\mathbb{k}$ a field.

Is it known whether this statement is true in the case that $\mathbb{k}=\mathbb{Z}$, rather than a field?

Alternatively, a counter-example would be great.

Comment: Quillen-Suslin theorem states that any projective module over your ring (or $\mathbb{Z}$ replaced by any PID) is free. It is in fact even more general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finitely generated projective modules are free over $R[x_1,\dots,x_m]$ for any PID $R$.  This was proved by Quillen in his original proof; I'm not sure about Suslin's proof.    See Lam's Springer monograph "Serre's Problem on Projective Modules".  (In fact all projective modules are free by a 1963 result of Bass.)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is true for PIDs and *even without Noetherianity*:  it suffices for your base ring $A$ to be a Bézout domain.  If you want a constructive proof, I think you can get away with assuming $A$ is a valuation domain or a finite-dimensional Bézout domain.

Recall that for a morphism of rings $A \rightarrow B$, a $B$-module $M$ is said to be extended from $A$ if there exists an $A$-module $M'$ such that $M \cong M' \otimes_A B$.  Note that a free $B$-module is always extended from a (free) $A$-module.  The big non-trivial result we need is the following:

> **Lequain-Simis:** If $A$ is an arithmetic ring (i.e. $A_\mathfrak{p}$ has totally ordered ideals for each prime $\mathfrak{p}$), then every f.g. projective module of $A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is extended from $A$.

This is proved, for example, in XVI.6 of H. Lombardi's *Commutative Algebra: Constructive Methods: Finite Projective Modules*, available [here](http://Commutative%20Algebra:%20Constructive%20Methods:%20Finite%20Projective%20Modules).  Note that the abstract induction given there in 6.12 is adapted to a concrete induction 6.13 due to I. Yengui with the additional assumption that Krull dimension is finite.

When $B = A[X] := A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ we can say more about extended modules.  The homomorphism $A[X] \rightarrow A$ sending polynomials to their constants gives us a way to send $A[X]$-modules to $A$-modules by extension of scalars.  Extension of scalars preserves f.g. and projective objects.  If $M$ is extended from $A$, then $M \cong M' \otimes_A A[X]$ so $M \otimes_{A[x]} A \cong M' \otimes_A A[X] \otimes_{A[x]} A \cong M' \otimes_A A \cong M'$.  Thus if $M$ is extended from $A$, then extension of scalars of $M$ along $A[X] \rightarrow A$ is inverse to extension of scalars of $M$ along $A \rightarrow A[X]$, and in particular, if $M$ is f.g. projective and extended from $A$, then $M$ is extended from an f.g. projective $A$-module.

Our elementary remarks up to this point allow us to deduce the following:

> Let $A$ be a ring which has f.g. projective modules free.  Then $A[X]$ has f.g. projective modules free iff $A[X]$ has f.g. projective modules extended from $A$.

Applying this to the result of Lequain-Simis we thus see that **any arithmetic ring having f.g. projectives free is a good Quillen-Suslin ring**.

Two important classes of such rings come to mind.

(1) *Chain rings*, i.e. rings in which ideals are totally ordered.  They have f.g. projectives free already because they are local, and local rings have *all* projectives free.

(2) *Bézout domains* (domains in which f.g. ideals are principal).  To see that Bézout domains have f.g. projectives free, we´ll sketch a quick proof that Bézout domains are characterized as having f.g. submodules of free modules free.  Indeed, if $A$ is Bézout and $M \subseteq F$ with $F$ free, then we can first assume $M \subseteq A^n$ by the f.g. hypothesis.  The ideal $I$ generated by the first coordinate of $M$ is f.g. since $M$ is, and hence is principal by the Bézout assumption.  Let $K = \ker(M \rightarrow I)$.  Principal ideals of domains are free, so the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow K  \rightarrow M \rightarrow I \rightarrow 0$ splits.  Since $K$ is a f.g. submodule of $A^{n-1}$, we conclude by induction on $n$.